# Apache settings, multi vhost multi servername same directory

Tags: apache, subdomain

I would like to know if it s possible to use the same  block to set up different servername for one vhost. I have an application that is reachable by www.extranet.com i would like to access it through any sub domain like www.exemple.extranet.com without having to declare them all.

I could use server alias but i need to keep the original URI on the browser.

Any Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best method would to be to use the rewrite rules. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com [r=301,L]
```

Comment: This would alter the original url no ?

Comment: Yes. But why would that matter? It modifies it well before you serve a page.

Comment: Yes it matters, i need to keep the entry url :) Got my answer from a friend, for those you need it :

Answer (score 0):

This is the main use-case for `ServerAlias`. The vhost responds to not only the `Servername`, but also all `ServerAlias`es. The only thing you need to "declare" is the list of hosts that this vhosts answers to.

```
ServerName example.net
ServerAlias www.example.net www.subdomain.example.net anothersubdomain.example.net
```

The hostname in the browser will stay the same.

Unless you do something about it with `RewriteRules` and such, but your goal was to not alter it. So the default behaviour should work for you.